# Any reason why my horizontal rules aren't working?

Tags: discussion

Any reason why my horizontal rules aren't working on [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/417710/is-there-a-specific-word-for-a-genius-who-can-express-themselves-via-original-in) question? Do they show up for you?

Currently, only one appears in my browser. I just checked again, and before, neither was.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are.

[image: Screenshot of question]

Comment: that more or less answers the question, can't see me getting a better answer. ha, thanks!

Comment: Without more details, like OS and browser, and whether you have any zoom, it's difficult to say. It looks like you have zoomed to less than 100%, which may mean that lines can disappear.

Comment: strange one does and not the other!

Comment: No: zoom can do that. It depends where on the monitor pixel grid the line ends up.

Comment: interesting, thanks.:)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ah, so that explains why the two lines have two different thicknesses when I change zooms.

Comment: Arguably this is a browser bug. A horizontal rule shouldn't disappear at certain page rescales. It should scale more gracefully. I can reproduce this in the current releases of Chrome and Firefox, but not in Edge.